# How do I combine identical cells in a column using python xlwt?

Tags: python, django, xlwt

I use python xlwt to generate an excel file (report). I can't combine the cells of the column with the same values (column A and column with totals) in any way.
For example, I have attached screenshots of how I get the output now and what kind of output it needs to be brought to.

My function generates a report of the following type:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZWn4.png)

Please help me to make it look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCWCu.png)

Report generation function:

```
def export_excel(request):

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = ("attachment; filename=Numbers_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y")) + '.xls')
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Numbers', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    row_num = 0
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True
    columns = ['Подразделение',
               'Номер',
               'Сумма',
               'Итог (Сумма+ндс+абон.плата)',
               'Итог по подразделению']

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    rows = ReportFilter(request.GET,
                        queryset=Parser.objects.all().values_list(
                            'attachment__attachment',
                            'number',
                            'pay',
                            'result')).qs

    rows1 = Numbers.objects.filter(is_enabled=True).values_list('attachment__attachment', 'number')

    res = 0
    temp = []

    for item1 in rows:
        temp.append(item1)
        res += item1[3]

    for item2 in rows1:

        if Parser.objects.filter(number=item2[1]):
            None

        else:
            item2 = list(item2)
            item2.append(250)
            item2.append(250)
            res += item2[3]
            item2 = tuple(item2)
            temp.append(item2)

    temp.sort()
    temp = tuple(temp)

    for row in temp:
        row_num += 1

        for col_num in range(len(row)):

            if isinstance(row[col_num], datetime.datetime):
                date_time = row[col_num].astimezone(datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=7))).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
                ws.write(row_num, col_num, date_time, font_style)
                ws.write_merge(1, row_num, 0, 0, f'{str(row[0])}')

            else:
                ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)
                ws.write(row_num + 1, 2, 'ОБЩИЙ ИТОГ:', xlwt.easyxf('font: bold 1'))
                ws.write(row_num + 1, 3, res, xlwt.easyxf('font: bold 1'))

    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

Thank you in advance for your help.